# is it possible to overlay two graphs (line and bar) in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard, elasticsearch-plugin, kibana-5

I am creating few graphs in Kibana to show statistics about the process. I have graph which takes how much time process took each time we ran the program. I show that using bar charts, however it would be nice to have a **line graph** on top of this bar graph to show **average** and **standard deviation**, which would help more to understand if duration it took is good or not.

if it's not possible in kibana, is there any third party utility for showing graphs, I mean something which fetches the data from Kibana and I can configured graph and create dashboard. I know this could be achievable using my own web application (sping or django) but that would be too much an effort. I need something like plug and play solution.

[image]

Comment: You should maybe have a look at timelion - available by default in Kibana 5.x, available in Kibana 4 as a plugin

Comment: Try using https://github.com/mstoyano/kbn_c3js_vis